# display data from db using keyword

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display all the data from the database which contains the same word which the user input. The code is working but the problem is that it is only displaying one result. Example like if i enter the word 'ACTIVE', it returns only one result. But i have two data which has the 'ACTIVE' word. I'm not sure what to do. Please help me this is for my project.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <h3>Search Lecturer</h3>
    <input class="text" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">
    <hr/>
    <h3>Details</h3>
</div>
    <table class="table-fill">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Lecturer ID</th>
            <th class="text-left">Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Email</th>
            <th class="text-left">Phone</th>
            <th class="text-left">Status</th>
            <th class="text-left">Gender</th>
            <th class="text-left">Address</th>
            <th class="text-left"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-hover">
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if($_POST["submit"]){
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($_POST['search']));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM LECTURER WHERE LCT_ID LIKE '%$search%' OR LCT_NAME LIKE '%$search%' 
            OR LCT_PHONE LIKE '%$search%' OR LCT_STATUS LIKE '%$search%' OR LCT_EMAIL LIKE '%$search%'
            OR LCT_GENDER LIKE '%$search%' OR LCT_ADD LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td class="text-left">'.$row['LCT_ID'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_NAME'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_EMAIL'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_PHONE'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_STATUS'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_GENDER'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_ADD'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="text-left"><a href="lctdlt.php?id='.$row['LCT_ID'].'" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">Delete</a></td>';
            echo '</tr>'; 
        }
    }
  }
}
else{
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM LECTURER");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td class="text-left">'.$row['LCT_ID'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_NAME'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_EMAIL'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_PHONE'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_STATUS'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_GENDER'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left">'. $row['LCT_ADD'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-left"><a href="lctdlt.php?id='.$row['LCT_ID'].'" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">Delete</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

With:

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```